# alert when script loaded

Tags: javascript, load, alert

I can load external scripts with this code:

```
newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
```

But I looked this page: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp
And I tried my new code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.onload = 'loaded();';
newScript.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);

function loaded()
{
alert('The script is loaded');
}
</script>
```

But it dont worked. I want to get an alert when script is loaded

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ln7M/1/
Here is the link

Comment: change "on load" on the left to "no wrap".

Comment: I can't understand. Can you give a example?

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/4Ln7M/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:

`newScript.onload = 'loaded();';`

To:

`newScript.onload = loaded;`